# How to implement Python in HTML file (.html) using pyscript?

Tags: python, html, pyscript

At first I create a .py file for the whole coding, but I realize that .py file can't run in browser (except localhost). Then I want to change the format to .html.. but im not sure about the pyscript techniques..[I am getting this error after change several coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvsDx.png)

```
PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py", line 201, in result raise self._exception File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 232, in __step result = coro.send(None) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 506, in eval_code_async await CodeRunner( File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 241, in __init__ self.ast = next(self._gen) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 142, in _parse_and_compile_gen mod = compile(source, filename, mode, flags | ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST) File "", line 41 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is my initial .py file that combine html and python coding.

```
import re
import webbrowser
import requests
import cgi
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
from selenium import webdriver


print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
print("<html>")
print("<head>")
print("<link rel='icon' href='homograph.png'>")
# print("<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>")
print("<title>HomoSearch Engine</title>")
print("<link rel='stylesheet' href='barstyle.css'>")
print("</head>")

print("<body>")

# TELEGRAM ID  
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

userid = form.getvalue("userid")  
if len(userid) == 9: 

    if form.getvalue("domainsearch"):
        domainsearch = form.getvalue("domainsearch")  
                
        # CHECK DOMAIN
        domainlist = 'domain.txt'
        with open(domainlist) as checklist:
            domainlist = checklist.read()

        # validate domain
        regex = "^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]" + "{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)" + "+[A-Za-z]{2,6}"
        pattern = re.compile(regex)
        if re.fullmatch(pattern, domainsearch):
            if domainsearch in domainlist:
                webbrowser.open('https://www.' + domainsearch)
            else:
                def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):
                    bot_token = '<cannot shared to others>'
                    bot_id = form.getvalue("userid")
                    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + \
                        '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_id + \
                        '&parse_mode=MarkDownV2&text=' + bot_message             
                    response = requests.get(send_text)    
                    return response.json()
                
                telegram_bot_sendtext("WARNING FAKE DOMAIN DETECTED")
                root = tkinter.Tk()
                #root.withdraw()
                tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Homograph Tool", "Warning!! \n"
                                                        "Suspicious domain detected! \n"
                                                        "There are typo or misspelling in the domain entered")
        else:
            webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + domainsearch)
else:
    webbrowser.open('http://localhost/python/error.html', new=0) 

# Using HTML input and forms method
print("<div class='container'>")

print("<div>")
print("<button type='submit' name='back' class='box'>")
print("<a href='' class='text'>Back</a></button>")
print("</div>")

print("<form action='' method='post' class='search-bar'>")
print("<input type='text' placeholder='Enter domain here' name='domainsearch'>")
print("<button type='submit'>")
print("<img src='images/search.png'>")
print("</button>")
print("</form>")

print("</div>")
print("</body>")
print("</html>")
```

This code will run a search bar that used google.

1. When the user enter a fake domain, it will alert the user with tkinter popup and telegram notification.
2. If the user enter a valid domain, it will direct to the genuine website.
3. If its not a domain, it will go to google search.

After change to .html file, my coding become like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/homograph.png">
    <title>HomoSearch Engine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="barstyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <button type="submit" name="back" class="box">
                <a href="bar.html" class="text">Back</a>
            </button>
        </div>

        <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false" class="search-bar">
            <input type="text" name="domainsearch" id="domainsearch" placeholder="Enter domain here">
            <button pys-onClick="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
                <img src="images/search.png">
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <py-script>
        from js import document

    def submit(*ags, **kws):
        userid = document.getElementById('userid').value;
        if len(userid) == 9:

            if form.getvalue("domainsearch"):
                domainsearch = document.getElementById('domainsearch').value;  
                        
                # CHECK DOMAIN
                domainlist = 'domain.txt';
                with open(domainlist) as checklist:
                    domainlist = checklist.read();

                # validate domain
                regex = "^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]" + "{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)" + "+[A-Za-z]{2,6}";
                pattern = re.compile(regex);
                if re.fullmatch(pattern, domainsearch):
                    if domainsearch in domainlist:
                        webbrowser.open('https://www.' + domainsearch);
                    else:
                        def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):
                            bot_token = '<cannot share to others>';
                            bot_id = form.getvalue("userid");
                            send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + \
                                '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_id + \
                                '&parse_mode=MarkDownV2&text=' + bot_message;         
                            response = requests.get(send_text);
                            return response.json();
                        
                        telegram_bot_sendtext("WARNING FAKE DOMAIN DETECTED");
                        root = tkinter.Tk();
                        #root.withdraw();
                        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Homograph Tool", "Warning!! \n"
                                                                "Suspicious domain detected! \n"
                                                                "There are typo or misspelling in the domain entered");
            else:
                webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + domainsearch);
        else:
            webbrowser.open('http://localhost/python/error.html');
    </py-script>

</body>
```

Im expect to able run this in .html file so i can implement in my (https) website for my project.

Hopefully someone can help me to solve this problem since im new to pyscript.

Comment: line 41 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax...

Comment: Your code will not work in PyScript. Features like this one do not exist inside the web browser: `webbrowser.open()`